# passing parameter to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function

I´m trying to wrap some indexeddb specific functions to a object. But it stumble across a parameter passing problem.

```
function DB_LINK_ROLE()
{
    this.general = new DB_LINK();
    this.cacheindex = new DB_LINK();
    this.locals = new Array();
    this.updatelist = new Array();
    this.checkwait = new WAIT_COUNTER();
}

DB_LINK_ROLE.prototype.init = function()
{
    this.checkwait.target++;
    this.general.req = indexedDB.open("gtn");
    this.general.req.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    // {...} other code
    this.general.state = 2; // Problem
    }
}
```

Obviously, the this object inside the function contains the event specific data. but i want to access the DB_LINK_ROLE() object property.

is there any possible way doing this?

Comment: Any idea what happen to the answer with some good discussion? Anyway, you can read more about Javascripts with this url: http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/ . In the section talking about lexical (static) scope, it should becomes clear to you why assign this to that in init function then call that in onupgradeneeded function works.

Comment: Maybe the other guy deleted his answer? However, you helped me a lot! I will read that link, hope that will explain me this scope behavior. Thank you very much, @Will